# Get token from service-account using kubectl describe

Tags: kubernetes, service-accounts

I just learned a month using kubernetes but i have problem after i apply file serviceaccount and get from serviceaccount, i don't have token from describe serviceaccount. How to i get token from serviceaccount ?

[image: picture file]

[image: picture apply]

describe serviceaccount name

[image: picture describe]

Answer (score 4):

you need to request a service account token, as [after this release](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/108309) the default token is no longer available.

```
kubectl create token SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME
```

> Secret API objects containing service account tokens are no longer auto-generated for every ServiceAccount.

[create-token](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-token-em-)